# How to prevent absolute position <ul> inside <li> to change its width?

Tags: background, html-lists, absolute

I'm trying to achieve [this effect](http://i50.tinypic.com/301j961.png).

Say we have this structure:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Guides</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Epics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Road Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Equipments</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this simplified CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    height:30px; /* So the ul#menu's height isn't changed by the ul#menu>li>ul */
    overflow:visible; /* So the ul#menu>li>ul is visible on ul#menu>li:hover */
    background: #e69646;
    box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0 #666;
}

ul#menu>li>ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:inherit; /*  */
    box-shadow:inherit;
}
```

The problem is that having ul#menu>li>ul on absolute positioning makes it lose it's background gradient and shadow. `background:inherit` and `box-shadow:inherit` yield [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/bh6L5/).

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Thank you in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it - http://jsfiddle.net/bh6L5/3/

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Guides</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Epics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Road Map</a></li>
            <div id="fake">Guides</div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="guides.html">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="guides.html">Equipments</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then add this to your css

```
#fake {
    position:absolute;
    width:45px;
    height:31px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background: #e69646; 
    z-index:999;
    top: -31px;
    left:0px; 
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
}
```